# How to format html onliner?

Tags: vim

Say I have a line of html code,

```
<div><p><span>foo</span></p></div>
```

I want to convert it to something like

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span>foo</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Is there any plugins or native solution to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) program (or [its HTML5 sibling](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5)).

That's what it has been designed for and that's what regular expressions are not designed for.

Comment: its not actually true, you can do anything in regex

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida romainl means that is not the job for regex. Not the right tool for that. didn't mean that regex cannot do it.  You can open a beer using screwdriver of course.

Answer (score 1):

if you work on linux box, usually `xmllint` was already installed. try this command:

```
:%!xmllint --format -
```

this will change the text to what you wanted. but there is `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the beginning. don't know if it is ok for you.

if you want to remove, after executing the command, the cursor will be at  line, type dd to remove. or you can write it in a mapping.

Answer (score 1):

`:%s/></>\r</g`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>gg</kbd><kbd>Shift-v</kbd><kbd>Shift-g</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

(you will nee to `:set ft=html` if you haven't already)

When I do the above, I get

```
<div>
    <p>
    <span>foo</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately VIM does really poorly with most front-end related indenting (html, javascript). It's a common complaint, and will probably never have a good solution despite all of vim's customizable power.